# Is it possible to import all variable from an object?

Tags: scala

If I have an object in a package is it possible to import and execute all commands from another package?
Ex:

```
object Example {
  val fakeMap: Map[Int, Int] = Map()
  fakeMap += (0 -> 1)
  def aFunction(a: Map) = {
    a += (1 -> 2)
    return a
  }
}
```

is it possible to automatically execute creating fakeMap and adding the value, other than:

```
import package.Example

val aMap = Example.fakeMap
val newMap = Example.aFunction(aMap)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you asking if it's possible to import an object and then invoke all the functions contained in it?  Not generally, no, because how would such a process know what values to supply for the functions' parameters?  How would the computer know that you want to supply `fakeMap` as the parameter to `aFunction`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a wildcard import:

```
import package.Example._
```

(In Java, you'd use `import static` for the same thing.)

This will import all members of the `Example` object, so you can invoke them without referencing the class name:

```
val aMap = fakeMap
val newMap = aFunction(aMap)
```